# can not run my app and my error is :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac

Tags: react-native

i run "react-native run-android" and it failed ,this picture is my result

and

my build.gradle is: i think it is right but not working

```
enter code here
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
}}allprojects {
repositories {
 google()
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    flatDir() {
     dirs 'libs'
     }
    maven {
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
}
```

and app/build.gradle is

```
 compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ir.yana.sample"
    minSdkVersion 16

    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
```

thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your buildToolsVersion to "28.0.3"

`compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'`

then sync gradle. I hope it's work for you.

Comment: Thank you for answering, 
I did it, but unfortunately it still fails